# Access files without fileshare

Tags: windows-8, wireless-router

Using Windows 8, is there a way to connect to a computer on your home wireless router and access their files like a server without having to set up any file share program?

**Note:** I want to not use homegroups or have to do anything to the other computer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No additional "file share program" is needed. Windows 8 provides a few different ways to share files and resources. The traditional method is to mark a file or folder to share as a "public folder". Windows 7 & 8 also have *homegroups*, through which you can specify who has access.

See *Sharing files and printers*, http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/sharing-files-printers-help#sharing-files-and-printers=windows-81&v1h=win81tab1&v2h=win7tab1&v3h=winvistatab1&v4h=winxptab1 for the traditional method that works with other versions of Windows.

*File sharing essentials*, http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/file-sharing-essentials#1TC=windows-7, explains both processes.

Comment: Oh, sorry for not specifying, I am trying to not use home group or do anything with the remote computer, just directly connect using the command prompt or something like that.

Comment: If you've set up a file share, it can be accessed from the command prompt. The system would not be very secure if you did not need to set up a share.

Comment: I thought so, I just wanted to clear it up by asking this website. Thank you